# Google location history... wild anomaly

Tags: google-location-history

Was driving home today from a trip up north and decided to check my journey on Google's location history after I got back. Phone is a Nexus 5 running Android 5.0. The locations mostly correct apart from one obvious wild location - which is clearly impossible. Any ideas what could have happened?

[image: location history is drunk]

Comment: It's definetely not a duplicate, but an issue with cell tower reporting wrong location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also had this happen, though when tracking my location for an exercise app.

I assume that I connected to a WiFi network unknowingly and that network was routed through a proxy in that far-away location. Thus, Google thought that I was farther away. I started turning off my WiFi when using that exercise app to track my location.

The root of this is that Google uses a combination of GPS, wireless network, and WiFi information to determine your location. Of these three, the WiFi is most likely to yield an incorrect answer.